# ProgressBar not Gone after pressing Register button

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with my code, I'm trying to make a Registration system using Firebase, it's just that after I press the button to Register, the Progress Bar is not Gone and keeps spinning and a warning message that Registration failed or succeeded does not appear.

here is my code (Layout)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/waves_atas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="420dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/wave"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_nm"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/waves_atas"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/waves_atas"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emaillogin"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/emaillog"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_daftar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.81"
    app:tint="@color/pucat" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textregisemail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/pucat"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/robotocondensedregular"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/pucat"
    android:hint="@string/atur_email_anda"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/passwordlogin"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/key"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_daftar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35000002"
    app:tint="@color/pucat" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textregispassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/pucat"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/robotocondensedregular"
    android:hint="@string/atur_password_anda"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/pucat"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordlogin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/passwordlogin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/passwordlogin"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_daftar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/radius"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
    android:text="@string/daftar"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textregispassword"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/passwordlogin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/waves_atas"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textsatu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/robotocondensedregular"
    android:text="@string/sudah_memiliki_akun"
    android:textColor="@color/pucat"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_daftar"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button_daftar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_daftar"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/kelogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="@color/biru_ng"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.07"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textsatu"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textsatu"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userregis"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/key"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/emaillogin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53"
    app:tint="@color/pucat" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textuserregis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/pucat"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/pucat"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/robotocondensedregular"
    android:hint="@string/masukan_username_anda"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/userregis"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userregis"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userregis" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />
```

here is my code (Java)

```
private TextView registerUser;
private EditText editTextUserName, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daftar);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    registerUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_daftar);
    registerUser.setOnClickListener(this);

    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textuserregis);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textregisemail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textregispassword);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_daftar:
            registerUser();
            break;

    }
}

private void registerUser() {
    String fullName = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (fullName.isEmpty()) {
        editTextUserName.setError("Isi username anda");
        editTextUserName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Tentukan Password Anda");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Isi email anda");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        editTextEmail.setError("mohon gunakan email yang valid (contoh = seseorang@gmail.com)");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Mohon atur password anda");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.length() < 6) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Minimal terdiri dari 6 karakter");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        User user = new User(fullName, email);

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(daftar.this, "Registrasi Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(daftar.this, "Registrasi Gagal, Coba lagi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(daftar.this, "Registrasi Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I am very grateful if you can help me.

Comment: So you're asking a question regarding Android, and your code is just a 'Hello' in HTML ?

Comment: im paste the wrong code, im sorry, now it's fixed

Comment: I recommend setting a breakpoint on all of the `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` lines, running in the debugger, and seeing if any of the breakpoints get hit. If not, that'd explain why the progress bar remains.

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed? If not, is any of the onComplete even triggered?

Answer (score 0):

> *I recommend setting a breakpoint on all of the progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); lines, running in the debugger, and seeing if any of the breakpoints get hit. If not, that'd explain why the progress bar remains*. 
>  by 
> [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)

The Answer is Correct, Thanks.
im trying this one and the problem is Database lives in a different region.